# getting an error stating "no column named shelter" attempting Post from postman

Tags: python

This is my database code and as far as I can tell I created a column named `shelter`

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    shelter = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

`shelter` also makes an appearance here

```
def __init__(self, shelter, password, email, location):        
    self.shelter = shelter
    self.password = password        
    self.email = email
    self.location = location

class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('shelter', 'email', 'location')

user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

@app.route('/user', methods=["POST"])
def add_user():
    shelter = request.json['shelter']
    email = request.json['email']
    password = request.json['password']
    location = request.json['location']
```

And it also appears here

```
new_user = User(shelter, password, email, location)

db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()

user = User.query.get(new_user.id)

return user_schema.jsonify(user)
```

This is the error message I receive from both the application terminal and the response from `postman`

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named shelter
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (shelter, email, password, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (&#x27;shelter1&#x27;, &#x27;devingoodrich91@gmail.com&#x27;, &#x27;testing&#x27;, &#x27;Salt Lake City&#x27;)]
```

Comment: `class User` doesn't create columns automatically and first you should create all columns in database manually. Eventaully you would have to check if module which you use to work with database has function `.create()` or methods to `migrate` changes.

Comment: what modules do you use ? `sqlalchemy` ? `flask`? You should add this as tags.